# Access row relatively with position number in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I've this source of data https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo

I want to select "Time Series (1min)" and then first record from it - because the time changes and then "1. open".

I tried to use this query

```
= Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo"), 1250)
= Source[#"Time Series (1min)"]{0}[#"1. open"]
```

But I get:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type List.
Details:
    Value=Record
    Type=Type
```

This didn;t helped me http://excel-inside.pro/blog/2015/11/05/absolute-and-relative-references-in-power-query/ I think the problem might lay that I'm getting null when referencing first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo"), 1250),
#"Time Series (1min)" = Source[#"Time Series (1min)"],
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(#"Time Series (1min)"),
Value = #"Converted to Table"{0}[Value]
in
Value
```